# Amplify GraphQL adding nested Inputs to Connections

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

I have created the following schema which up until yesterday would generate `Input` using the `@connection` reference `ID`. I created a new API which is now creating an `Input` with the actual nested `type` as part of the `Input` for some of the types. E.g:

```
type Metadata
    @model(subscriptions: null)
    @versioned
    @auth(
        rules: [
        ]
    ) {
    id: ID!
    merchant: Merchant! @connection

}

type Merchant
    @model(subscriptions: null)
    @versioned
    @auth(
        rules: []
    ) {
    id: ID!
    metadata: Metadata! @connection

}
```

would create the Input types:

```
export type CreateMerchantInput = {
    id?: string | null,
    merchantMetadataId: string,
};

export type CreateMetadataInput = {
  id?: string | null,
  merchant: MerchantInput,  <-- Contains this!!
  metadataMerchantId: string,
};
```

The Appsync schema shows this too, so it's something on my machine that has compiled the main GraphQL schema and pushed it. Really scary that different machines can compile it differently!!

Does anyone have any ideas what I have changed or am missing or have specified in my schema or Amplify CLI config please?